# Azure Logic App - Determine what triggered an SQL Server "When item is modified" condition

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps

I have an Azure Logic App with an SQL Server "When an item is modified (V2)" trigger. So, every time a row is added or modified in the target table, it triggers the action (it sends a Service Bus message, in this case). What I need to know is if there is any way to distinguish when the action was triggered by a new row from when it was triggered by an updated row. My intention is to send different messages to Service Bus queue depending on what triggered the action (a new row or a modified row).

Is there any way to do that?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is it like the duration it took from the last updated row to the latest or the time which it got triggered?

Comment: No, "When an item is modified (V2)" triggers the action when a row is inserted or when a row is modified. What I'm asking is if there is a way to know exactly what event triggered the action, a new row inserted or an existing row modified

Comment: you can do both trigger are separate create like AFTER INSERT,after UPDATE  then you get action both separate.

Answer (score 0):

you can create Variable for Action Like This.

```
DECLARE @Action as char(1);
    SET @Action = (CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED)
                         AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED)
                        THEN 'U'  -- Set Action to Updated.
                        WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED)
                        THEN 'I'  -- Set Action to Insert.
                        WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED)
                        THEN 'D'  -- Set Action to Deleted.
                    END)
```

In Action Variable you get right action like insert or update.

Comment: @David it is right for your question ? if yes then right the answered of other user can see right answer.

Comment: Sorry Piyush, but I don't understand where in the Logic App do I have to declare that variable

Comment: declare variable in trigger after catch action and do you apply your logic.